# How we can filter cities on the bases of state selected in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const statesAndCities = [
    { state: "Telangana", cities: ["Hyderabad", "Warangal"] },
    { state: "Madhya Pradesh", cities: ["Gwalior", "Bhopal"] },
    { state: "Rajasthan", cities: ["Jaipur", "Jaipur City"] },
    { state: "Chattisgarh", cities: ["Raipur", "ABC"] }
  ];
  const [value, setvalue] = useState([]);
  const [city, setcity] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setvalue(e.target.value);
    setcity(statesAndCities.find((state) => state === e.target.value));
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        {statesAndCities.map((elem) => {
          return <option value={elem.state}>{elem.state}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        {statesAndCities.map((elem) => {
          return <option value={elem.cities}>{elem.cities}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How we can filter cities on the bases of state selected in React. What logic do I need to write in handle change for display cities on the basis of states selected

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it this way:

```
  const [firstSelectValue, setFirstSelectValue] = useState('');
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFirstSelectValue(e.target.value);
    const selectedState = statesAndCities.find(el => el.state === e.target.value);
    setCities(selectedState.cities)
  };
```

And in your second select you can map through these cities:

```
  <select onChange={citiesOnChange}>
        {cities.length > 0 && cities.map((city) => 
          <option value={city}>{city}</option>;
        )}
  </select>
```

You will also need to make state for your second select as well as a function for handling changes for this select (e.g. citiesOnChange). Additionaly, you should disable the second select if the user didn't choose the value from the first select.

Answer (score 0):

You would need `state`, `cities` and `selectedCity`. `cities` will change whenever the user selects a different `state`. `selectedCity` will change whenever user selects a different *city* from `cities` state, *but also* whenever the user changes `state` for a better UI/UX design.

Here's how you can go about it:
[image: Edit infallible-sea-nqy5s9]

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const statesAndCities = [
    { state: "Telangana", cities: ["Hyderabad", "Warangal"] },
    { state: "Madhya Pradesh", cities: ["Gwalior", "Bhopal"] },
    { state: "Rajasthan", cities: ["Jaipur", "Jaipur City"] },
    { state: "Chattisgarh", cities: ["Raipur", "ABC"] }
  ];

  const [state, setState] = useState(statesAndCities[0].state);
  const [cities, setCities] = useState(statesAndCities[0].cities);
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState(cities[0]);
  console.log(
    "state:", state,
    "& cities:", cities,
    "& selectedCity:", selectedCity
  );

  const handleStateChange = (e) => {
    setState(e.target.value);

    // Find "cities" that belong to the selected "state"
    const matchingCities = statesAndCities.find((item) => {
      return item.state === e.target.value;
    });
    setCities(matchingCities.cities);

    // When we change state, also change the selectedCity
    setSelectedCity(matchingCities.cities[0]);
  };

  const handleCityChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedCity(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select onChange={handleStateChange}>
        {statesAndCities.map((elem) => {
          return (
            <option key={elem.state} value={elem.state}>
              {elem.state}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
      <select onChange={handleCityChange}>
        {cities.map((city) => {
          return (
            <option key={city} value={city}>
              {city}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
      <h2>Selected city: {selectedCity}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```